# the button click redirect to the page based on selected options in jsp

Tags: jsp

how to move to maize.jsp or wheat.jsp,while the user selects either "maize" or "wheat" option and click ok button 
thank u! 
the sample code is here

```
     <form action="index.jsp" method="post">
         <select name="Crop_Type">

          <option  onchange = "maize.jsp" value="maize">maize</option>
          <option onchange = "wheat.jsp" value="wheat">wheat</option> 
          </select>
        <input type="submit" value="OK" name="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: use javascripts to redirect on user selection. and specify target page in value of option tag, no need of onchange.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a servlet. "hen the user submit the form the action is to go to the servlet you created. That servlet views which option the user selects and then redirects to maize.jsp or to wheat.jsp.
In this case the form will look like this:

```
<form action="**myservlet**" method="post">
     <select name="Crop_Type">

      <option name="maize" value="maize">maize</option>
      <option name="wheat" value="wheat">wheat</option> 
      </select>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

The other way is to use javascript. In this case, you use a javascript function that is used to set the the action attribute of the form, depending on the selected option. In this case the code may look like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="myform">
     <select id="Crop_Type">

      <option value="maize">maize</option>
      <option  value="wheat">wheat</option> 
      </select>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" name="submit" onsubmit="myFuncion"/>
</form>
```

And the javascript function will look like this:

```
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("Crop_Type").selectedIndex;
   var y = document.getElementById("Crop_Type").options;
   var form = document.getElementById("myform");
   if(y[x].value = "maize") {
      form.action = "maize.jsp";
   } else if (y[x].value = "wheat") {
      form.action = "wheat.jsp";
   }

   // true means that the form is valid and can be submited
   return true;
}
```

There are many other ways to do this.

Hope to be useful